# Generic parser for configuration with circe-config

Tags: scala, enums, configuration, circe

I have an enumeration:

```scala
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import enumeratum.{Enum, EnumEntry}
import io.circe
import io.circe.config.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.extras.auto._

sealed trait MyEnum extends EnumEntry

object MyEnum extends Enum[MyEnum] {
  case class Foo(a: String) extends MyEnum

  object Foo {
    def parse(config: Config): Either[circe.Error, Foo] = config.as[Foo]
  }

  case class Bar(b: Int) extends MyEnum

  object Bar {
    def parse(config: Config): Either[circe.Error, Bar] = config.as[Bar]
  }

  def values = findValues
}
```

Like this I can parse a configuration file with `typesafe-config` and `io-circe`.
What I would like to do, is to define a single parse method which parses my configuration based on the input type.

```scala
sealed trait MyEnum extends EnumEntry

object MyEnum extends Enum[MyEnum] {

  def parse[T <: MyEnum](config: Config): Either[circe.Error, T] = config.as[T]  

  case class Foo(a: String) extends MyEnum

  case class Bar(b: Int) extends MyEnum

  def values = findValues
}
```

Then I'd use like this:

```scala
val config: Config = ???

val result = MyEnum.parse[Foo](config)
```

Unfortunately it's not compiling, what am I missing? Is it possible?

Comment: I am pretty sure the compile error should say something about an implicit not found or that `T` is not supported. You need to provide an implicit evidence that such types are parseable.

Comment: Indeed, that's the error: `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type io.circe.Decoder[T]`. But, how to provide such an implicit?

Comment: `def parse[T <: MyEnum : Decoder](config: Config)` then you need to either use the `auto` or `semiauto` derivation, check the [docs](https://circe.github.io/circe/codec.html). - In any case, it would be good if you first learn about the [**typeclass** pattern](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) and about how [**implicits** work](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html). Those are fundamental topics for using those libraries.

Comment: This is how I also tried, I've used `Decoder`, but it was not working because I've used `io.circe.generic.extras.auto._` instead of `io.circe.generic.auto._`. With the later one is working, though the `extras.Configuration` property is not applied anymore.

Comment: That is another question or at least edit this one to include all the details.

Comment: just give circe what it asks for: 

`implicit val decoder = deriveConfiguredDecoder[Foo]`